# remove certains characters at the beginning of a line with awk

Tags: unix, awk

I would like to remove some characters that can be at a beginning of a line, with awk. The characters I would like to remove are `@` and/or `=`

Here is a file example :

```
@word <= Remove @
=word <= Remove =
@=word <= Remove @ AND =
=@word <= Remove = AND @
```

At the moment, I use `sub(/^\@/, "", $0)` to remove `@` at the beginning of a line. How can I edit this line so it removes `@`, `=` and both if they are present together ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In awk:

```
$ awk 'gsub(/^[=@]+/,"")||1' file
word <= Remove @
word <= Remove =
word <= Remove @ AND =
word <= Remove = AND @
```

Explained:

```
awk '
gsub(/^[=@]+/,"") || 1  # replace all leading =s and @s with "" and print nevertheless
' file
```

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{sub(/^[@=]+/, "")}1' File
```

With `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/^[@=]+//' File
```